# PostgreSQL - Partitioning of a Table with Sensor Data

Tags: postgresql, triggers, partitioning

I am currently working on a scenario where a table is filled with sensor data every *x* minutes. The sensor data is inserted into the table by using cronjobs.
Suffering from performance problems, I decided to partition this specific table. This should be done by using a `Trigger`, which should be executed **before** every `INSERT` Statement and `FOR EACH ROW`. The first step would be to backup the data in the table, and then import it into a new table, where the `Trigger` is doing the partitioning.

My question now is, what would happen if I run the import of the data and simultaneously get data from different cronjobs? Will the data, inserted by the cronjobs, wait until the import is finished or will it result in an Error since a `Trigger` cannot run concurrently?

Is there a more convenient way to solve this specific problem? I was also thinking of running the `Trigger`, responsible for the partitioning, after the `INSERT` has been queried on the main table, and then move the inserted data from the main table, which should be empty if partitioned, to the corresponding partition (table)?

Comment: Triggers can absolutely run concurrently - why do you think they wont? Also: did you consider [native declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#ddl-partitioning-declarative) in Postgres 10? Then you don't need any triggers at all

Comment: why not RULES instead of triggers?..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Do they? I have read some Articles about Triggers not being able to run concurrently. Yes I know about native declarative partitioning, but I in my case I am not able to update the database as it runs on an older version.

Comment: Don't know which articles you read, but if they claim triggers don't run concurrently you should remove those sites from your bookmarks. But still: an upgrade to Postgres 10 might be worthwhile (not only for the partitioning but also because of many performance improvements)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was reading some Articles and also some questions about this topic which can be found in the Mailing List of the official PostgreSQL website. Nevertheless, I think that I have maybe came across some other questions, which do not fit into this scenario. I will make some testing and check how the Trigger behaves when importing multiple backup files. Thank you!